# Multiply a databasevalue with a result of a loop

Tags: php, sql

Ive currently got this code where I have two loops: one which displays all my ToDos and one which counts the amount of hours ive worked on a certain ToDo. 
What I want to do is to multiply the ['pris'] (cost pr hour) with the amount of hours ['timer'] from the loop.

```
echo "<div id='innhold'>";

$db = kobleTil();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oppdrag";
$resultat = $db->query($sql);
while($nesteRad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<hr />";

    echo "<table id='resultat'>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan='7'>" . $nesteRad['navn'] . "</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><b>Type</b></td><td><b>Startdato</b></td><td><b>Sluttdato</b></td><td><b>Pris pr. time</b></td><td><b>Aktiv</b></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['startDato'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['sluttDato'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['pris'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $nesteRad['aktiv'] . "</td>";
    echo '<td><a href="oppdrag.php?oppdrID=' . $nesteRad['oppdrID'] . '">Se på</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="litime.php?oppdrID=' . $nesteRad['oppdrID'] . '">Legg til timer</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="slett.php?oppdrID=' . $nesteRad['oppdrID'] .  '">Slett</a></td>';
    echo "</tr></table>";
    echo "<hr />";

    $prisx = $nesteRad['pris'];

    }

echo "<a href='lioppdrag.php'><h5>Legg inn nytt oppdrag</h5></a>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<h3>Statistikk - Oppgaver arbeidet mest med<br /></h3>";

$statistikk = "SELECT oppdrag.*, (SELECT SUM(timer) FROM timeregistrering  WHERE timeregistrering.oppdrID = oppdrag.oppdrID) AS Timer FROM oppdrag ORDER BY  Timer DESC";
$print = $db->query($statistikk);
while($rad = $print->fetch_assoc()) {

    $timer = $rad['Timer'] . '00px';
    echo "<b>Oppdrag: " . $rad['navn'] ." Antal timer: " . $rad['Timer'] . " </b><br/>";
    echo "<img src='firkant.png' id='firkant' width='"; echo $timer; echo "'></img><br/><br/>";

    $timerx = $rad['Timer'];

    }

echo "</div>";
} else { 
echo "<div id='innhold'>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Logg inn for å se innholdet</a>";

echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to set you in the right direction but without the exact tables I can't give you the exact answer.  first I'd do this in SQL before you ever get to PHOP and loops.   Think in terms of set's not loops, so group your todo's and sum(timer) for each group. Then you can do another column with the sum(timer)*pris calling it Total.  Psuedocode would be something like

```
select ToDo.Name, sum(working.timer), sum(timer)*ToDo.Pris as Total 
from ToDo join working on todo.id = working.todo_id 
group by ToDo.Name
```

(and a where clause to restrict the dates worked probably unless you just want everything)

edit: sorry I'm not sure why the code didn't show up when I first looked at the question and I only saw it after I answered but I still think this might help so take a look and let me know

Comment: `select oppdrag.navn, sum(timeregistrering.timer), sum(timer)*oppdrag.pris as Total 
from oppdrag join timeregistrering on timeregistrering.timeID = timeregistrering.oppdrID 
group by oppdrag.navn` #1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'prosjektphp.oppdrag.pris' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: you can put the oppdrag.pris in the 3rd expression inside the sum paren's.  Since it's in the same table as oppdrag.navn it might also recognize it in the group by clause, group by oppdrag.navn, oppdrag.pris.   but I'd just move the parenthesis and it should work